# Difference between the docker images for aspnet (aspnet version, host os codename, ect.)

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

What is the difference between the docker images below?

- mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
- mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1-buster
- mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim

I see all these tags listed with the same docker file:
*3.1.11-buster-slim, 3.1-buster-slim,  3.1.11, 3.1*

Reference: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet/

I've read some details for the java images, so i guess the format is

> [aspnet version]-[host os codename]-[features included]

but then it's not clear to me why event the *[features included]* tag points to the same docker file description or if the naming concept is the same as the JDK one.

Comment: Those specific images are identical, but you could specify a different base Linux distribution (`3.1-alpine`) or version (Ubuntu-based, `3.1-bionic`, `3.1-focal`).  Debian "Buster" is the default for this image if you don't pick anything specific.

Comment: Thanks @David Maze! Why *-slim the points to the same docker file?

Comment: This particular image doesn't seem to have a non-slim variant, but in the question I linked to above, other images like OpenJDK do.

Comment: You can also find documentation on .NET's Docker tagging scheme at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/documentation/tagging-guidelines.md